# android 6.0 make error: package not found

Tags: android, makefile, java-7, java

I'm building android 6.0 on my host. First, the error says lots of packages don't exist on my host.

```
frameworks/opt/net/voip/src/java/android/net/sip/SipProfile.java:26: error: package javax.sip does not exist
import javax.sip.InvalidArgumentException;
                ^
frameworks/opt/net/voip/src/java/android/net/sip/SipProfile.java:27: error: package javax.sip does not exist
import javax.sip.ListeningPoint;
                ^
frameworks/opt/net/voip/src/java/android/net/sip/SipProfile.java:28: error: package javax.sip does not exist
import javax.sip.PeerUnavailableException;
```

And finally, build failed due to symbols not found error.

```
  symbol:   class RequestEvent
  location: class SipSessionGroup
frameworks/opt/net/voip/src/java/com/android/server/sip/SipSessionGroup.java:1761: error: cannot find symbol
        } else if (evt instanceof ResponseEvent) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class ResponseEvent
  location: class SipSessionGroup
frameworks/opt/net/voip/src/java/com/android/server/sip/SipSessionGroup.java:1762: error: cannot find symbol
            return ((ResponseEvent) evt).getResponse().toString();
                     ^
  symbol:   class ResponseEvent
  location: class SipSessionGroup
Note: frameworks/opt/net/voip/src/java/com/android/server/sip/SipService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: frameworks/opt/net/voip/src/java/com/android/server/sip/SipService.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
582 errors
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/voip-common_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41

#### make failed to build some targets (01:26 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I follow exactly the building steps on android official [website](https://source.android.com/source/building.html)

And I also using `openJDK 1.7` as required. Here is my `jdk` version:

```
alan@new$java -version
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone give me a hint on this ?

**Update**

It seems that package `javax.sip` is not included in `jdk1.7`, where could I find that package ? Now, I think this is the key to this question.

Comment: in 6.0 you have to run time permissions have get related permissions?

Comment: @SohailZahid I'm building the whole android system. I don't get you.